# Javascript Object passing itself in as a parameter

Tags: javascript

I have an object with some information. On the other hand I have a store, holding many objects of this object type.

The single object should be able to delete itself from this store.
My store knows a function "DeleteObjectFromStore" with a parameter of this object.
Now I want to pass in the object itself but I don't know which syntax to use.

The store:

```
class NoteStore {
    constructor() {
        this.notes = []; // Collection of all notes
    }

    DeleteNote(note) { // Delete this object from the store
        var index = this.notes.indexOf(note);
        if (index > -1)
            array.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

And my object

```
class Note {
    constructor(noteTitle, noteText, noteStore) {
        this.title = noteTitle; // name
        this.text = noteText; // content
        this.store = noteStore; // dataStore
    }

    CreateDeleteButton(parentDiv) { // Create a button for deleting itself
        var data = this.store;
        var deleteBtn = document.createElement("input");
        deleteBtn.type = "button";
        deleteBtn.value = "Delete";
        deleteBtn.onclick = function() {
            data.DeleteNote();               // <= missing parameter!
        }
        parentDiv.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    }
}
```

So using the keyword this is not correct. Then I would pass in the button.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Are you trying to remove `Note` instance from `this.notes`? Where is `array` defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a name for this outside the function:

```
CreateDeleteButton(parentDiv) { // Create a button for deleting itself
    var data = this.store;
    var noteObj = this;
    var deleteBtn = document.createElement("input");
    deleteBtn.type = "button";
    deleteBtn.value = "Delete";
    deleteBtn.onclick = function() {
        data.DeleteNote( noteObj );               
    }
    parentDiv.appendChild(deleteBtn);
}
```

Comment: Or: `deleteBtn.onclick = function() { data.DeleteNote(this); }.bind(this);`